# [FLUTTER]Button not responsive on Samsung Phone

Tags: flutter, button, samsung

I am developing a Mobile app, and install on a lot of Android Phone, but when I install my app on Samsung (A50 - last update - full access for my app. Every function work well, except last function in Video, how could I fix this problem? Is it problems with One UI?
Video on Samsung Phone:
[Samsung Phone with Problem](https://streamable.com/hi9esn)
and video for my phone:
[Other phone work well](https://streamable.com/q40xa3)

I hope a full solutions for this problems :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try to run your app in debug mode with Samsung A50 phone. Then post your error message here. So, we can give some better suggestions.

Comment: can you share the code of your button

Comment: here is my code for the button:

Comment: [code](https://pastebin.com/tVW5t5mN)

Comment: Try to change your widget from GestureDetector to ElevatedButton or TextButton

Comment: @Aks I will try with your suggestion and feedback you soon ^^